# Non blocking log writing on REST API

Tags: php

On PHP API I'm using log to file and when there are high concurrent requests the logging become bottleneck because of writes blocking.
Looking for solution that will be reliable and fast as possible.
Thought about writing from PHP to socket service which will write to file and then to process the file and save it to db.
Does it should work ? someone did it and can point me to reference ?
Are there better solutions for handling writing log during request without using database ?

Comment: Yes, there is. Write log to an in-memory stream as events holding only unformatted raw-data and in the background as an independent process - handle them (sending to slow I/O, network or anything else). That's classic approach. AWS prometeus supports that out from the box afaik